# How to create executable jar for testNG with configurable parameter and get the output as pass fail for each test case

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, testng, continuous-delivery

How to create executable jar for testNG with configurable parameter and get the output as pass fail for each test case

I have a TestNG maven project and currently all the parameter are passed from .properties file, i want to move the project to continuous integration GoCD tool in which i have to make this project in executable jar format and all the parameters are passed using CLI and send the output in the form of pass and fail for each test cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can package your tests (from test class path) into jar like described [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html). Then in another module you create regular executable jar, CLI or whatever, which depends on testware.jar and executes TestNG tests programmatically.